# How can I know where the location the last character in a multi line UILabel is placed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to render a UIImageView the moment after a multi line UILabel has finished. Some examples of the current state of the app.. aka the problem:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
myLabel.text = @"One of the earliest and most deadly complaints about Kelvin Rudd is now being leveled at Bill Shorter";
[myLabel sizeToFit]; //or use :- [myLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

due to this your label size become fixed and you can add image accordingly.